# Обособление "конечно же"

Tags: пунктуация

Сегодня вечером попробовал написать тотальный диктант на сайте. Там была фраза:

> Зимних игр в те времена, конечно же, не было, потому что в Элладе не было ни ледовых арен, ни горнолыжных трасс.

Так и не пойму, почему *"конечно же"* надо было выделить запятыми. Разве это вводный оборот в данном случае? Где-то прочитал, что *"конечно"* может быть усилительным словом. Разве это не тот случай?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сейчас не могу вспоминать или искать правила, но если в двух словах говорить.

Иногда бывает, что обособление "конечно" зависит от воли автора, как в примере типа *"Он поступил(,) конечно(,) некрасиво* - здесь можно выбирать, но это не наш случай. В функции усилительной частицы - или чего-то подобного, не помню точно систематику - "конечно" бывает обычно при обстоятельствах ну или при определениях. И при этом без "же". Усилительная частица "же" говорит скорее всего о том, что "конечно" - это отношение автора.

Наверное есть исключения, но я не вижу причин искать их в нашем примере. тут явно "конечно же" передает отношение автора, а не что-то еще.

Comment: *>> Иногда бывает, что обособление "конечно" зависит от воли автора, как в примере типа "Он поступил(,) конечно(,) некрасиво"* Интересно, какой автор может здесь не обособить...

Answer (score 3):

В словаре *Остроумовой* и *Фрамполь   **"Трудности русской пунктуации. Словарь вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений"*** говорится, что слово ***конечно***, произносимое тоном уверенности, убеждённости, без паузы перед следующим словом, **может** пунктуационно не выделяться:

*Ну конечно же он целил в меня, да только всё время промахивался.*

Но в предложении из тотального диктанта я бы запятыми ***"конечно же"*** выделил бы. А вот если бы вместо ***"потому что"*** (*"конечно же, не было, **потому что…**"*) в нём было бы ***"ведь"***  — думаю, **в отдельно взятом предложении** (лучше было бы знать контекст!) для меня возможен был бы и вариант без запятых:

***Зимних игр в те времена конечно же не было: ведь в Элладе не было ни ледовых арен, ни горнолыжных трасс.***

Comment: Спасибо! Только я не очень понимаю разницу. И исходное предложение у меня в голове и звучит без всяких пауз.

Answer (score 1):

В справочнике "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" указано, что "конечно" не обособляется только в ответных репликах: Это правда? - Конечно правда!

Это можно объяснить переносом логического ударения на слово "конечно" и отсутствием паузы. Но вот похожая ситуация в присоединительном предложении: "**И конечно же** присутствует доверие, иначе быть не может". Здесь, вероятно, не нужна запятая, ударение на "конечно же".

**Еще примеры с усилительным значением:** Марина захмелела, ей сделалось теплее, и она неожиданно стала рассказывать, как они познакомились с Данилой,  и очень хвалила солдат-спутников, в первую голову старшего вагона Оноприйчука, который **конечно же** вместе с солдатами скоро усёк, что Данила и Марина никакие не брат и сестра, но не прогнал их... (Виктор Астафьев. Пролетный гусь (2000).
Всё барахло надо было убирать и приводить в жилой вид кладовку **конечно же** самой Марине (Виктор Астафьев).

Заданное предложение надо перестроить, чтобы не обособлять вводное слово: Зимних игр конечно же тогда не было, потому что в Элладе не было ни ледовых арен, ни горнолыжных трасс.

Comment: *"конечно" не обособляется только в ответных репликах* - слово "только" здесь *конечно* неуместно.

Comment: Вы правы, наверное, действительно лишнее. С другой стороны, они другие варианты не рассматривают.